# Kalitte Dynamic Dashboard Widget Editor Location

Tags: .net

I am using the kalitte toolkit from http://dynamicdashboards.net/ and we are having a request to change the widget editor/config modal popup location to the top instead of centered.

Looking through the Class widgetControlInfo I couldn't find anything to change the location of the config modal.

How would I move the config modal to the top of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently do not support this feature.

we will add this feature on next version.

I also added my tasks.

Regards

E-Mail :berkay@dynamicdashboards.net

Answer (score 2):

If you override style in page which contains the dashboard, you can achieve this. Sample is shown in below.

```
.x-window { top: 0px !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try this out and let you know the results.